# Why does Tuple not have a Monad instance?

Tags: haskell, tuples, monads

One thing I noticed was that `Tuple` does not have a `Monad` instance.

Tuple does however have an `Applicative` instance:

```
instance Monoid a => Applicative ((,) a)
```

Which already extremely heavily restricts what we can make the `Monad` instance be.

Lets look at the type signature we would get for join:

```
instance Monoid a => Monad ((,) a)

join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a

join :: Monoid a => (a, (a, b)) -> (a, b)
```

We can also look at the Monad laws:

```
join $ f <$> pure x == f x
join $ f <$> (mempty, x) == f x
join (mempty, f x) == f x
join (mempty, (a, b)) == (a, b)

join $ pure <$> x = x
join $ pure <$> (a, b) = (a, b)
join (a, (mempty, b)) = (a, b)
```

At this point we know that combining `mempty` and `x` in either way results in `x`. And the only type information we have about `x` is that it is a `Monoid`. So basically the only two implementations are:

```
join (a, (b, x)) = (a <> b, x)
```

and:

```
join (a, (b, x)) = (b <> a, x)
```

And the second one of those makes `ap` and `<*>` not the same.

So now we know that the only valid `Monad` instance for `((,) a)` is:

```
instance Monoid a => Monad ((,) a) where
    (a, c) >>= f = let (b, c') = f c in (a <> b, c')
```

So why is that not currently the case?

Comment: I guess it's new with `ghc-8.1` - `ghci` says `instance Monoid a => Monad ((,) a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’`

Comment: A wild guess: because it isn't general enough? It may be the reason why `Set` doesn't have one...

Comment: `Set` has no monad instance because no instance can exist that satisfies the monad laws. The proposed instance fo `((,) a)` is law-abiding, and I think is the only possible law-abiding instance, so it makes sense to create it.

Comment: Don't instances have to be as general as possible? I cannot seem to think of another data type which needs constraints, which is why it seems like a too restrictive instance IMO

Comment: I've usually just used [the Writer Monad](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more) instead...

Comment: @ThreeFx This is as general as possible. Also, not having the instance at all would be even more restrictive. And, as Michael mentioned, this instance already exists in the latest stable version of GHC.

Comment: @ThreeFx How in the world is this instance more restrictive than not having an instance seeing as it is the only possible law abiding instance. Also I mentioned another data type that needs constraints at the very beginning of my question: `instance Monoid a => Applicative ((,) a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems like the answer to this question is that I just have to use `ghc-8.0.1`, which does give `Tuple` a `Monad` instance. Credit to @Michael for pointing this out.

Comment: `8.1` is not yet out; he meant `8.0.1`. The instance can be found [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#control.i:ic:Monad:Monad:25).